# Maven dependency of Java API for dotCMS

Tags: java, api, dotcms

I'm trying to create a new project and just starting to do some hands on for creating/updating new content through Java/REST API of dotCMS.
But I'm not able to find the maven dependency or the jar for the API anywhere.

http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=dotcms gives no results.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the info- dotCMS maintains its own repo which is why you couldn't find it:

```
<repository>
    <id>repo.dotcms.com</id>
    <name>repo.dotcms.com-releases</name>
    <url>http://repo.dotcms.com/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dotcms</groupId>
    <artifactId>dotcms</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for.